# delete cell on different sheet if cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clean up my workbook by deleting some cells on another sheet if the cells are empty (Later on I also need to remove a Column on another sheet)
unfortunately this just deletes the cells on the sheet containing the button

I tried the following:
(edited)

```
Sub Delete_cells()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
 If ws.Name = "Inlife" Or ws.Name Like "'Inlife (*)'" Then
If Range("C22") = "" Then
Range("B22:C22").Delete Shift:=xlUp
If Range("C23") = "" Then
Range("B23:C23").Delete Shift:=xlUp


End If
End If
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me get back on track?

Comment: `Range("C22:C23").Value` is an array (2 cells), you can't compare it to a string

Comment: `Set ws = Sheets("Inlife") Or ws.Name Like ("'Inlife (*)'")` is an incorrect syntax

Comment: When talking about an error, you should say what error, on which row. Anyhow, `Set ws = Sheets("Inlife") Or ws.Name Like ("'Inlife (*)'")` does not make any sense. It should be commented, not being of any help. And also `Range("C22:C23").Value = ""` Is wrong. Being only two cells you should use `Range("C22").value = "" And Range("C23").value = ""`.

Comment: that I had before but then i got the problem it would only delete the cell on the sheet that I ran the macro from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
...

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
  If ws.Name = "Inlife" Or ws.Name Like "'Inlife (*)'" Then
    If ws.Range("C22").Value = "" AND ws.Range("C23").Value = "" Then
      ws.Range("B22:C23").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
  End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

You can't check different cells at once, you need to check all of them separately.

Comment: ah, I see.. Thank you all ;)

Comment: You're welcome.